# 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' displays error

Tags: android

in my application i want to add Firebase MLKit but when i add firebase library in app gradle like

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:16.0.0'
```

That time

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

gives error

i also try to add

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

but it will still give error.

[image]

Comment: hover the error and type them here

Comment: try to add all the dependencies shown in the error with new version or if you don't need them just remove the dependency group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select the Project from list

[image]

then goto

> project/.idea/libraries

and check which **support libraries are different**

[image]

If you got that then add these libraries manually in **gradle dependencies**

Then sync your project again..

Answer (score 0):

Add this in Module app build.gradle Try this, hope it may help you :-

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Sync and build the code.

Comment: still not working ma'am